# Rabbitmq Key based Authentication

Tags: node.js, erlang, rabbitmq, mqtt

Background: I am very new to RabbitMq, I just installed it and tried playing with it.

So, I Have RabbitMq running on ec2(ubuntu) , and a node.js server as a RabbitMq client running on local machine (for pub/sub over websockets) also I have enabled MQTT protocol on RabbitMq so thats running on port 1883

With node.js I used [MQTTClient](https://github.com/leizongmin/MQTTClient) But whenever node.js server connects with RabbitMq, an error is raised, **Connection Refused: bad user name or password**

I am planning to use a Key based authentication for RabbitMQ server, so that the websockets from browser sends a encoded string, which node.js server decodes and gets a KEY and sends that KEY to RabbitMQ , then RabbitMQ decides if this exists or not.

I have found another Great RabbitMQ Plugin, [rabbitmq-auth-backend-http](https://github.com/simonmacmullen/rabbitmq-auth-backend-http) but this asks for username / password , which can be Key / Id combination.

I am looking for suggestions, How Do I achieve this?

Also one more problem is none of the node.js client sends username/password , so does it means I have to write a node.js client also?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That MQTT client does seem to support username and password, try setting them in the options object you pass in when creating a connection.  The default RabbitMQ user is `guest`, with the password `guest`.

I don't understand why you would use RabbitMQ as an authentication back end, since it's a message queue, not an identity store. The auth plugin you mentioned seems to allow you to use another HTTP server to authenticate clients to RabbitMQ, but not allow RabbitMQ to handle identity management.

Comment: Sorry! I didnt understood what RabbitMQ is. But anyways, I have decided to use ZeroMQ instead. :)